# Access to Stack Exchange sites from Egypt is denied. What is happening?

Tags: support, error-message

In Egypt we (most of us) are getting an error message while browsing any of the Stack Exchange sites that says "Access Denied", what is going on or why ?
[image: Stack Exchange, Access Denied]

Comment: It seems like there was issues with that IP address, such as spam, so Stack Exchange blocked it as a preventive measure.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sorry... My bad. There was an HTTrack based scraper hitting the SO feeds a few million times a day that I was trying to block, and it looks like I accidentally banned all of [TE Data](http://www.tedata.net/eg/en/About-Us/About-Corporate).

This should be fixed now. Sorry for the disruption.

Interesting side note: We average about 9 requests per second from Egypt for SE/SO. You can also see the spikes from the scraper (only partial logs until auto rate limiter kicked in):

[image]